# Perl script error: uninitialized value error in perl

Tags: perl, initialization

I am getting the following error:

"Use of uninitatlize value $gi in concatenation <.>or string at fillename.pl line 32,  line 4."

This message is repeated for all the opened files but line line changes to line 5 after the first.

I can't determine how to fix it! The files i'm opening are standard fasta files with the following format where the first line contains the sequence information and the lines that follow are the sequences.
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#open files from data directory
opendir my $data_dir, "data" or die "Unable to open directory!";
my @files = readdir $data_dir;    #reading files into array

#Taking only files with .fa extention
my @fa_files = grep /\.fa$/, @files;
my @sorted_fa_files = sort @fa_files;

#Taking each .fa and reading description line
foreach my $filename (@sorted_fa_files) {
    open my $filehandle, "<", "data/$filename" or die "Unable to open file!";

    while ( my @file_contents = <$filehandle> ) {    #setting aray to contain all file contents
        chomp @file_contents;
        print "filename: $filename\n";

        my $description_line = shift @file_contents;    #setting array to contain description line only
        my $join_seq = join "", @file_contents;

        #extracting description line contents individually
        my @description_parts = split /[\|\.]/, $join_seq;
        foreach (@description_parts) {
            my $gi              = $description_parts[1];
            my $accession_id    = $description_parts[3];
            my $version         = $description_parts[4];
            my $seq_description = $description_parts[5];
            print "gi number: $gi\n";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error says `$gi` is undefined. You should put the statement `print $_ . "\n";` inside that `foreach loop` and see what the code is actually doing.

Comment: thank you! I found my error!